# HTML5 Cache Manifest Links are Broken when Offline

Tags: html, offline, cache-manifest, broken-links

I've successfully implemented a HTML5 cache manifest file to store locally the pages and resources of my web app so that portions of it may be viewed while the user is offline.

The problem I'm running into, is that if the user starts on `www.example.com/` and then navigates from there to `www.example.com/products/`, the links on the `www.example.com/products/` page are broken (are missing part of the URL path) and revert to my `FALLBACK` offline page, indicating that they are not stored in the `CACHE`, although I explicitly told them to be stored.

Here's a section of my cache.manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Version 0.0.1

http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/products/
http://www.example.com/products/item-page/

FALLBACK:
/ http://www.example.com/offline.php
```

When I navigate to the products page from the home page, everything works as expected. When I then click the link to navigate to the `item-page`, the browser shows my `offline.php` page, indicating that `http://www.example.com/products/item-page/` is not stored in the cache.

Am I missing something? Or why is this not working? Please help, and provide code/explanation :)

**EDIT** - I have `.htaccess` files redirecting my `index.php` pages to `directory/` (to remove `index.php` from the URL). This seems to be causing the problem with the cache, because when I change my links in my HTML from `item-page/index.php` to `item-page/` it works. Any ideas??

Comment: Is your link definitely to `http://www.example.com/products/item-page/` and not `http://www.example.com/products/item-page`?

Comment: The link on http://www.example.com/product/ points to http://www.example.com/product/item-page/index.php

Comment: But you don't have `example.com/product/item-page/index.php` in your manifest, why are you expecting it to be cached?

Comment: `example.com/products/item-page/index.php` IS in the manifest as `example.com/products/item-page/`. I leave off the `index.php` in the manifest because my `.htaccess` file redirects the `example.com/products/item-page/index.php` page to the `example.com/products/item-page/`

Comment: No it isn't.  For `example.com/product/item-page/index.php` to be in the manifest you have to actually put the URL `example.com/product/item-page/index.php` into it.  As far as the browser is concerned `example.com/product/item-page/index.php` and `example.com/product/item-page/` are two different URLs, it can't make guesses about which URLs refer to the same server resources.  Your `.htaccess` cannot redirect anything to anything if your server is offline.

Comment: If I type `example.com/product/item-page/index.php` the cache.manifest file fails (view with Safari Web Inspector) because it says `example.com/product/item-page/index.php was redirected` so the manifest file is not created.

Comment: So don't redirect it, or link directly to the URL that you want instead of to a URL you don't want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server redirects item-page/ to item-page/index.php, and redirects are not automatically cached.

You should

1. Add item-page/index.php to your manifest, in addition to item-page (they are actually two pages), or
2. Make item-page/ load the content you have for index.php, without the redirect

Answer (score 0):

If you add this section to your manifest file it should work

```
NETWORK:
*
```

Comment: All this does is include all files that are not specifically outlined in the manifest, and allows the cache of pages that contain the manifest in the `<html>` tag.